# Syntactic sugar explanation of Scala'a unapply method

Tags: scala, unapply

I am getting an error in the extractor step (unapply method call).
The error message is: Wrong number of arguments for the extractors. found 2; expected 0

Can someone please help what is causing the error (where my misunderstanding is).

```
class ABC(val name:String, val age:Int)  //class is defined.

object ABC{
    def apply(age:Int, name:String) = new ABC(name, age)  
    def unapply(x:ABC) = (x.name, x.age)                   
}


val ins = ABC(25, "Joe")  //here apply method is in action.
val ABC(x,y) = ins        //unapply is indirectly called. As per my understanding , 25 and Joe suppose to be captured in x and y respectively. But this steps gives error.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error I get is

> an unapply result must have a member `def isEmpty: Boolean`

The easiest way to fix this is to make `unapply` return an `Option`:

```
def unapply(x: ABC) = Option((x.name, x.age))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. Can you please let me know why my understanding is incorrect? What is understand is: 'ins' will be decomposed using unapply method and the returned values would be captured in  x and y respectively.

Comment: You may use `Some` instead of `Option` to tell the compiler the match is exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

The `unapply` method in an extractor which binds values must return an `Option`.  This is because there's no intrinsic guarantee that an extractor will always succeed.  For instance consider this massively oversimplified example of an extractor for an email address:

```scala
object Email {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[(String, String)] =
    s.indexOf('@') match {
      case idx if idx >= 0 =>
        val (user, maybeSite) = s.splitAt(idx)

        if (maybeSite.length < 2 || maybeSite.lastIndexOf('@') > 0) None
        else Some(user -> maybeSite.tail)

      case _ => None
    }
}
```

At the application site:

```scala
val Email(u, s) = "user3103957@stackoverflow.example.xyz"
```

Turns into code that's basically (from the description in *Programming In Scala* (Odersky, Spoon, Venners (3rd ed))):

```scala
val _tmpTuple2 =
  "user3103957@stackoverflow.example.xyz" match {
    case str: String =>
      Email.unapply(str).getOrElse(throw ???)
    case _ => throw ???
  }
val u = _tmpTuple2._1
val s = _tmpTuple2._2
```

Technically, since the compiler already knows that the value is a `String`, the type check is elided, but I've included the type check for generality.  The desugaring of extractors in a pattern match also need not throw except for the last extractor attempt.

Comment: You actually call the compiler the match will always succeed.